# Format 64gb SDXC card as NTFS file system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, sd-card

I've tried using Windows (8), Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), and Android (Samsung Galaxy S4) to re-format my old SD card.

It is currently formatted in `exFat`, and it seems that during an `rsync` 3 of my music files became corrupted, and now I can't seem to clear or re-format the drive.

**If I delete any data and then safely remove the drive, it is back when I re-insert it.**

On Ubuntu, I can't seem to get the SD card to mount directly using `exFat`, but I can get my `LG G4 (Android)` to mount via `MTP` with the SD card inside and read from it.

On my old Android phone `(Samsung S4)`, I can `mount` and `unmount` the card, and select the format option; however, at the end it just remounts the card and it still has 29 gb used out of 59 available (of the 64).

On, Windows, I've tried using the `Disk Management` to format it which went up to 99% and then failed... I've also tried `format` in `cmd` and `diskpart` to format the disk.

Nothing so far has worked...

Here is what I have from `format` in `cmd`:

```
C:\windows\system32> format E: /fs:NTFS /v:SDcard /q
Insert new disk for drive E:
and press ENTER when ready...
The type of the file system is RAW.
The new file system is NTFS.
QuickFormatting 59.5 GB
Creating file system structures.
The first NTFS boot sector is unwriteable.
All NTFS boot sectors are unwriteable.  Cannot continue.
Format failed.
Format failed.
```

Here is the commands I tried in `diskpart`:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.3.9600

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          238 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online           59 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> convert mbr

Virtual Disk Service error:
The specified disk is not convertible. CDROMs and DVDs
are examples of disks that are not convertable.

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> active

DiskPart marked the current partition as active.

DISKPART> format fs=NTFS label=SDcard quick

    0 percent completed

DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```

**=-=-=-=-=- EDIT -=-=-=-=-=**

Upon doing some more research, it appears there is an issue with sandisk 64gb SDXC cards, where they get locked into readonly mode, with this information, I tried the following:

*NOTE: When I plug in my card into Windows, I see 26.2 GB free of 59.4 GB; 33.2 GB is used -- so a little over half...*

```
C:\windows\system32> diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.3.9600

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: XXXXXXXXXXXX

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          238 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online           59 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             59 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

C:\windows\system32> chkdsk E: /X /R /offlinescanandfix
The type of the file system is exFAT.
Volume Serial Number is 0741-C987
Windows is verifying files and folders...
Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\data\obb\com.gramgames.tenten\com.samsung.music\com.spotify.mobile.android.ui\com.vcast.med
iamanager\com.levelup.beautifulwidgets.free\... all the directories look like they are combined into 1 big string here, so I snipped it for readability...
Corruption was found while examining files and directories.
Corruption was found while examining the volume bitmap.
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file \DCIM\Camera\337f2.mp4 of name 79617.
Corruption was found while examining files in directory \DCIM\Camera\ (348).
An error occurred while recovering lost files.
```

**=-=-=-=-=- EDIT #2 -=-=-=-=-=**

Upon trying to format it in various cameras, I was finally able to get it to load on my PC with Ubuntu (14.04), trying to run GParted got me the following output if I delete and create a new partition on the disk (if I try to format it, it shows as if it was successful, but the disk stays in exfat and the existing partiton doesn't get updated at all):

[image: Screenshot from GParted]

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this card simply is defective. Ever tried to read it from start to end using dd in Linux ? I expect this fails too.

Comment: The card has been fine for over a year, I used to mount it back when I was running Ubuntu 13.10; haven't mounted it since I upgrarded to 14.04. Mainly, since I switched from a Samsung S4 to an LG G4, and moved the SD card over, I ended up having 3 *.mp3 files which got corrupted when I did an rsync over MTP (USB plugged into the PC and phone). I think the reason is due to how lollipop may handle sd card access versus kit kat, but I'm not sure. A lot of posts about this kind of thing online make me think that since lollipop now supports rw in NTFS, it would be easier to use that with Linux.

Comment: I have seen many usb sticks and sd cards die from one second to the other. Androids support for this card with ntfs on it is one thing, but that Windows is unable to wipe it out is usually a bad sign

Comment: The card is currently exFat, which I think may be part of the problem, since access to it was via MTP and rsync. So I'd plug the phone into the PC via USB and run a custom bash script to get the mtp mount directory and do an rsync into the file system. This approach worked perfectly with my S4 on Kit Kat; but once I tried it on my G4 with Lollipop, 3 of the files I had on there before became corrupted.

Comment: @Marged the SD card will still play music files loaded on it, it's just that the volume bitmap is corrupt and I can't find a way to fix or reformat it. I do NOT (emphasis, not yelling) care about keeping / recovering / or backing up anything on this SD card. I just want it to be formatted with a clean MBR and partition table (preferably in NTFS).

Comment: @Marged It looks like at the root cause the drive got stuck in a read only mode and even using `diskpart` to set the attributes for the disk, it still stays in read only mode ( currently using windows, since ubuntu isn't recognizing anything in `/dev/sdc`...).

Comment: @Marged Added an edit, as it does seem that I was able to make a little bit of progress today, I think it may be possible to recover this disk now... recover as in reformat and use instead of junk; I still don't care to keep the data.

Comment: Why the downvote? Was there something wrong with how I asked my question? I checked a bunch of other answers on here before posting it and tried following a lot of them; and no matter what my issue was still unresolved, so I opened up this question.

Comment: There shouldn't be any other answers here on StackOverflow about recovering misbehaving SD cards... we do have sites for computer hardware and maintenance activities, but this one is for programming, only.

Comment: There's a strong chance your card is a fake... knockoffs often work (somewhat slowly) up to a point, but fail when you try to use the entire capacity.  You seem to be having trouble starting at half full.  Probably your expensive SD card is actually a 32 GB no-name model that's been relabeled.

Comment: @Ben Voigt -  I didn't want to put it on ask ubuntu or super user b/c it could be for either Windows or Linux, so I didn't want to limit my reach. I thought this was the general section of Stack Exchange, but I guess I was wrong. Can I request that this be moved? I'd highly doubt this is a fake card, unless Best Buy is settling fake cards, because I bought this from their store about a year and a half ago.

Comment: Superuser covers both Windows and Linux.

Comment: "Has been fine for over a year"? Well yes, things work fine and then they break and no longer work fine. Perhaps it broke due to unknown reasons / random chance. Perhaps it was defective in the sense of having an unusually small write limit / tolerance, and "worked fine" until it was reached. Cheap flash memory is like that.